# Touchpad does not exist

Tags: dell, touchpad

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 and I have opened Mouse & Touch-pad, but there is no Touch pad tap. I am using a Dell Inspiron 17R 7720 SE.

[image: desktop screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should reinstall the driver for touchpad.

1. First, delete your old `dkms` module, using [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal):

   `cd /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/`

   `rm -rf alps-dst-0.4`
2. Download the new driver fom [here](https://www.linuxwind.org/download/psmouse-alps-1.3-alt.tbz).
3. Install it, following next commands in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal):

> ```
> tar xvf psmouse-alps-1.3-alt.tbz
> cp -afr usr/src/psmouse-alps-1.3/ /usr/src/
> dkms add psmouse/alps-1.3
> dkms autoinstall
> rmmod psmouse && modprobe psmouse
> ```

Comment: Who compressed that??

Comment: but awesome. mulitouch scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for 12.04 for Dell laptops here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2102346

Maybe it'll work on 13.04 as well...