# Two finger scrolling does not work with ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, scrolling

I have a Dell inspiron 5720. I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04. My touch pad scrolling with two fingers, zooming with a pinch etc does not work. It works fine with my Windows 7.
I don't have a two-finger scrolling option in my mouse and touchpad tab of system settings.

I tried to follow this post.

```
http://askubuntu.com/questions/291143/ubuntu-13-04-touchpad-option-not-exists
```

but I dont see a dkms directory within my lib folder to do a `cd /var/lib/dkms/psmouse/`

How should I fix this?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Have edited the post.

Comment: This mean that you don't have installed `psmouse`. Just continue with step 2